# web.config file transformations

Tags: c#, asp.net, xslt, web.config-transform

We release updates to our product several times a year and we need to be able to make changes to customer's web.configs.

We want to be able to apply these changes via c#.

Has anyone used the [ctt.exe](https://ctt.codeplex.com/documentation) program and implemented a wrapper class for it? On initial tests it seems to strip all whitespace which isn't ideal.

Comment: Do you update web.config for each release per customer or there's only one web.config for all customers?

Comment: Each release could have changes and customers could have modified parts of web.config so we need to target as per web config transforms

Comment: Have you looked at slowcheetah? http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/69023d00-a4f9-4a34-a6cd-7e854ba318b5 Also I assume you know about the web.config.release

Comment: i'm aware of the visual studio methods, however these upgrades arent "published". So we need to be able to apply based on executing the transformation of the xml file via code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the Microsoft.Web.XmlTransform library which resolves this perfectly without needing 3rd party tools.

```
using Microsoft.Web.XmlTransform;
```

...

```
   using (XmlTransformableDocument document = new XmlTransformableDocument())
                using (XmlTransformation transformation = new XmlTransformation(transformFilePath))
                {
                    document.PreserveWhitespace = true;
                    document.Load(sourceFilePath);

                    var success = transformation.Apply(document);
                    if (!success)
                    {
                        string message = string.Format(
                            "There was an unknown error trying while trying to apply the transform. Source file='{0}',Transform='{1}', Destination='{2}'",
                            sourceFilePath, transformFilePath, destinationFilePath);
                        throw new Exception(message);
                    }

                    document.Save(destinationFilePath);
                }
```